# Change of variable in limits

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital, change-of-variable

Might be a silly question, or a complete lack of intuition from me, but I cannot figure out how to properly solve limits using some trivial variable change.

The example that triggered me is the limit you obtain while differentiating $e^x$:

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^h - 1}{h} = 1$$

From here, one could introduce the variable change $u = e^h - 1 \implies h = \ln(u + 1)$ and then obtain $\lim_{u \to 0} \frac{u}{\ln(u + 1)} = 1$. Now, one could again multiply both the numerator and denominator by $\frac{1}{u}$:

$\lim_{u \to 0} \frac{u}{\ln(u + 1)} \cdot \frac{\frac{1}{u}}{\frac{1}{u}} = \lim_{u \to 0} \frac{1}{\ln(u + 1) \cdot \frac{1}{u}} = 1$

I am just trying to understand if there is an underlying formal framework behind those substitutions or it only involves intuitive pattern recognition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is mainly a matter of tricky pattern recognition.

Usually the foundamental result proved as first step is that as $x \to \infty \implies \left(1+\frac1x\right)^x\to e$ and from here we can prove that both

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^h - 1}{h} = 1 \quad \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\log (1+h)}{h} = 1$$

which are indeed equivalent.

Comment: Is it possible to find the first formula without involving it in the limit calculation? From a formal pov

Comment: @gatosec Yes I think it is possible also prove indipendently that $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^h - 1}{h} = 1$. Maybe there is something on MSE on that.

Comment: For example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448771/lim-limits-h-to-0-fraceh-1h-1-and-the-relation-with-sinx-cosx) or also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2489317/proof-that-the-number-e-exists-based-on-the-following-definition).

Comment: but the power series is basically the binomial expansion of the Bernoulli formula, this is circular in a sense.

Comment: @gatosec The second link contains an argument completely independent.

Comment: Oh sorry. Was not updated here on my browser.

Comment: what’s interesting is that the Bernoulli formula is not directly related to the limit in my post, we usually say it’s e because we know it’s e in the first place, but how can you connect this limit definition to the number e without involving its very own definition? The posts you linked don’t really addressed this issue.

Comment: @gatosec : there are multiple approaches (and none of them being circular) to the theory of $e, \exp, \log$ and each approach has to start from somewhere. You should explicitly mention your starting point.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, after reading your blog, I had the answer to most of my questions. At least, regarding the theory behind the natural logarithm and direct consequences about differentiating exponentiation. However, I still do not understand how to handle limits properly, I lack fundamentals skills and I am prone to do invalid algebraic manipulations, especially when rewriting them.

Comment: In my OP, I mentioned the variable change $u = e^h - 1$, what is the formal basis behind this? Is there any rule of what variable change one should consider when encountering such limits? Or is it just invented _out of thin air_?

Comment: @gatosec: this is called rule of substitution for limits. You can see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1073047/72031

Comment: @gatosec: I have also written about limits in my blog. You may have a look at those posts starting from [this one](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2013/11/teach-yourself-limits-in-8-hours-part-1.html?m=0).